# Testing is still success even though assert failed in cypress

Tags: javascript, fetch, cypress

I'm fetching the real data via API and then check response is success or fail like this.

```
{ message: "fail" }
```

if the message is fail, I want to force test fail and also I want to check status is ok or not. Even if use throw new Error, testing is still success.

[image]

My codes like this

```
describe('fetch Data', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit('http://localhost:3000');
  });

  it('Fetch Data', () => {
    fetch('https://mocki.io/v1/82b25ba1-615a-4ff6-8c5d-c9f464f8c843').then((response) => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Something went wrong!');
      } else {
        return response.json();
      }
    }).then((res) => {
      expect(res.message).to.contain('success');
      cy.log('result => ', res);
    }).catch((err) => {
      throw new Error(err);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially the `fetch()` and subsequent `.then()` and `.catch()` are not running on Cypress queue, so it does not know when the test has finished.

You can convert the `fetch()` to `cy.request()` to get around that.

But to continue with fetch, use Mocha's `done()` method inside the catch block to signal end of test

```js
it('Fetch Data', (done) => {
  fetch('https://mocki.io/v1/82b25ba1-615a-4ff6-8c5d-c9f464f8c843')
  .then((response) => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Something went wrong!');
    } else {
      return response.json();
    }
  }).then((res) => {
    expect(res.message).to.contain('success');
    cy.log('result => ', res);
    done()
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    throw new Error(err);
    done()
  })
})
```

Removing the catch clause will also allow the test to fail.

```js
it('Fetch Data', () => {
  fetch('https://mocki.io/v1/82b25ba1-615a-4ff6-8c5d-c9f464f8c843')
  .then((response) => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Something went wrong!');
    } else {
      return response.json();
    }
  }).then((res) => {
    expect(res.message).to.contain('success');
    cy.log('result => ', res);
  })
})
```